# EditText без клавиатуры

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на EditText клавиатура не появлялась, но при этом можно было выделить текст на нем?

Comment: как избавиться от клавиатуры без отрубания курсора есть тут — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718005/267019

Answer (score 4):

В .xml

```
android:inputType="none" 
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Comment: Клавиатура не появляется, но при этом я не могу видеть выделение текста.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте для `EditText` [два атрибута](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173020):

```
android:inputType="none"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

у EditText есть такое поле "setShowSoftInputOnFocus". но работает только начиная с 21 Api. поэтому для новых девайсов сделал проверку на сдк версию:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        et.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    }
```

а в старых версиях андроида вполне работает вот такой способ отмены клавиатуры до её появления (причём на новых оно не работает):

```
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

совмещаем одно с другим, и вауля — по крайней мере на эмуляторах показывает то, что нужно. и с андроидом 4.4.2 и с андроидом 7.1.1
и на реальном смартфоне с 5 андроидом.

главное не забыть вставить в манифест

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

чтобы при запуске программы клава таки не вылазила