# запрет показа клавиатуры на android, но чтобы не скрывался курсор

Tags: android, android-edittext

в активности есть EditText. задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии на него курсор в месте нажатия был, но софтверная клавиатура не появлялась.

пробовал очевидное решение, запрещающее появление клавиатуры

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

но тогда не показывается курсор.

принудительное указание

```
android:cursorVisible="true"
```

не помогает.

как быть?

Comment: Подскажите какова цель такого уникального подхода?

Comment: калькулятор с "рукописной" клавиатурой (дабы были кнопки управления курсором и не было лишних кнопок) и возможностью вставлять цифры в середину строки. соответственно — моя клава висит всегда, а стандартная появляться не должна.

Comment: А перекроить стандартную клаву под свою не рассматривали такой вариант?

Comment: как вариант — сижу курю гугл. пока непонятно как сделать не полноценную клавиатуру, которую нужно устанавливать в систему отдельно, а чисто в конкретной программе.

Comment: Так у элемента EditText на этот случай есть атрибут inputType. Там посмотрите варианты которые доступны для выбора.

Comment: "очевидное решение" — это оно и есть. "отсутствие клавиатуры при имеющемся курсоре" в списке отсутствует

Comment: Там кроме как запретить показ клавы, можно еще и вид клавы выбирать. Например только цыфровая клавиатура. И потом прикрутить туда стрелки.

Comment: тоже вариант. но пока моё решение таки сработало :)

Comment: Вы используете EditText как TextView. Просто поменяйте виджет.

Answer (score 0):

в итоге что я нарыл:

есть у EditText такое поле "setShowSoftInputOnFocus". но работает только начиная с 21 Api. поэтому для новых девайсов сделал проверку на сдк версию:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        et.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
    }
```

а в старых версиях андроида вполне работает вот такой способ отмены клавиатуры до её появления (причём на новых оно не работает):

```
    InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

совмещаем одно с другим, и вауля — по крайней мере на эмуляторах показывает то, что нужно. и с андроидом 4.4.2 и с андроидом 7.1.1
и на реальном смартфоне с 5 андроидом.

главное не забыть вставить в манифест

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

чтобы при запуске программы клава таки не вылазила